# Confusion about $\epsilon - \delta$ language

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Suppose there is a function $f(x)$ and assume the limit exist as $x$ goes to $0$
$$\lim_{x\to0}f(x) = 0$$
then
$$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\exists \delta\gt 0, \text{ such that } |x| \lt \delta ,|f(x)| \lt \varepsilon \tag{1}$$

Can we also claim that, we can always find a $\delta_{1} \gt 0$ (an interval) such that
$$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\exists \delta_{1}\gt0, \text{ such that } |x| \lt \delta_{1} ,|f(x)| \leq \varepsilon \tag{2}$$

Where the two $\varepsilon$ in $(1),(2)$ are the same. **My question is**: Given that $(1)$ holds, does $(2)$ also hold? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So is your question whether we can find a $\delta_{1}$ **fixed** so that $|x| < \delta_{1}$ implies $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$?  If so, the answer is no.  To say "**there is some $\delta_{1}>0$ fixed such that for every $\epsilon > 0$, blah blah blah***" is to say "**$\exists \delta_{1} > 0 \forall \epsilon > 0$ such that blah blah blah.**"  This is *different* than saying "$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0$.  The order of $\forall$ and $\exists$ matters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

$$\forall\varepsilon\gt0,\exists \delta\gt0,\quad\text{such that}\ \space |~x~| \lt \delta \Rightarrow ~|f(x)| \lt \varepsilon \tag{1}$$

And yes, if $(1)$ holds then $(2)$ holds too. That's because in general $a \lt m$ implies $a \le m$.
If the two $\epsilon$ are the same, in $(2)$ just pick the same $\delta$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. Can you be more specific why $a \lt m$ implies $a \le m$

Comment: Because if a is smaller than m, it's also smaller than or equal to m. The opposite is not always true though. So if (2) holds you cannot use the same $\delta$ in (1) and claim it is also true.

Comment: @Strange What does $\leq$ mean?  It means "less than or equal to".  That means one of these has to hold: either **less than**, or **equal to**.  So since $1$ is equal to $1$, we can say $1 \leq 1$.  Also, since $2$ is smaller than $3$, we can say $2 \leq 3$.  Because of this reason, in general if $x < y$ then $x \leq y$.  Also, if $x = y$, then $x \leq y$.

Comment: Oh, do you mean the set $a \lt m$ contains the set $a \le m$, so if the first one happen, then the second one also happen?

Comment: In math, that's what we mean by implies, yes :)

Comment: Sorry, Typing error in the previous comment. It should be inverse, set $a \le m$ contains set $a \lt m$. So the smaller one happen implies the bigger one happen

Answer (score 1):

If (1) holds, then taking $\delta_1=\delta$ gives you (2).

If (2) holds, suppose we want to show (1) for a given $\epsilon$. By (2) there exists $\delta'_1$ such that $|x| < \delta'_1$ implies $|f(x)| \le \epsilon/2$. Then taking $\delta=\delta'_1$ gives the first definition since $|f(x)| \le \epsilon/2 < \epsilon$.

---

Comments: as Peter pointed out, there should be an implication "$\implies$" in (1) and (2). Also, I am assuming your question is mainly about the strict inequality vs the non-strict inequality. As user46944 points out, it is wrong to hope for a $\delta_1$ that works universally for any $\epsilon$. I answered your question under the assumption that $\delta_1$ depends on the chosen $\epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ;)